# How does this operator act on a function, and how does this change of co-ordinates work?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I'm currently reading a paper which considers the (polyharmonic) periodic Schrodinger operator

$$H = (-\Delta)^l + V(x), \ \ \ x \in \mathbb{R}^d,$$

where $\Delta$ denotes the Laplace operator on $\mathbb{R}^d,$ $V$ is some smooth, periodic, real function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ acting on a function $f$ by multiplication, and $l \in \mathbb{N}.$ The paper then says the following:

> Under a suitable affine change of co-ordinates, we can rewrite the operator $H$ as
>
> $$H = H_0 + V(x),$$
>
> where $H_0 = (\mathbf{DGD})^l,$ and $\mathbf{D}$ denotes the operator $i \nabla$ and $\mathbf{G}$ is a positive-definite $d \times d$-matrix.

The paper doesn't go into any further details here, so I have a few questions. Firstly, would I be correct to assume that, by $\mathbf{DGD},$ they mean

$$\displaystyle \mathbf{DGD} = -\sum_{\substack{1 \leqslant i \leqslant d} \\ {1 \leqslant j \leqslant d}} a_{ij}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j},$$

where $[a_{ij}]$ is the matrix $\mathbf{G}$? Then, raising that to the power $l$ represents multiple compositions of that operator with itself?

Furthermore, could someone show me how exactly this "affine change of co-ordinates" works in this instance, to yield that expression for $\mathbf{DGD}$? That is, is there an explicit way to write such a change of co-ordinates?

Comment: I'm not really sure what they want, $-\Delta=-\sum_k \partial_k^2$ in cartesian coordinates, so simply with $\mathbf{G}=\mathbb 1$ you get what you want. Can you link to the paper?

Comment: See page 3 of [this paper,](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.3096v1.pdf) which takes $l = 1$.

Comment: Alright, I misunderstood the question. I will write up how it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are missing the point: In the article they claimed that under a change of coordinate we have 
$$H = H_0 + V(x),$$
with the potential $V$ being smooth **and periodic with the lattice of periods of $V$ equal $(2\pi \mathbb Z)^d$** (emphasis mine).

Let $\Lambda$ be the lattice of periods of $V$. that is, 
$$V(x) = V(x+ 2\pi \lambda),\ \ \ \text{for all }\lambda\in \Lambda.$$ 
Let $A$ be the matrix (the affine change of coordinate) which sends $e_i$ to $\lambda_i$, where $\{\lambda_1, \cdots,  \lambda_n\}$ spans $\Lambda$. Let $\widetilde V (y) = V(Ay)$, then $\widetilde V$ is $(2\pi \mathbb Z)^d$ periodic. Let $g(y) = f(Ay)$. If we write $x = Ay$, then $g(A^{-1} x) = f(x)$. Thus 
$$-\Delta f(x) + V(x) = 0$$
translates to 
$$-\Delta (g\circ A^{-1}) (y) + \widetilde V(y) = 0.$$
Calculating $-\Delta(g\circ A^{-1})$ gives 
$$-\Delta (g\circ A^{-1}) = DGD, \text{where } G = (A^{-1})^TA^{-1}.$$

Comment: Quickly done, I was losing myself in a giant write-up trying to explain how differentials change under coordinate switches, which is where I had pinpointed the main problem.